SQL to join 2 tables - one row value divided into multiple rows on another table
I have 2 table that I want to join:
Order table



Item
Order_num
Qty




A
123b
3


A
123c
4



Cust_order table



item
cust_ord
qty




A
12v
2


A
frg4
4


A
gtd.
1



The desired output is based on qty in cust_order table, Order number from order table gets assigned to cover the qty. Order table qty is divided among order table and the order number signifies which qty is assigned to which cust order



item
cust_ord
qty
Order_num




A
12v
2
123b


A
frg4
4
123c


A
gtd.
1
123b



Any help is highly appreciated!
I am trying to rank and add the details but it's not working

Have you tried anything???

I think the values in your item column are incorrect or you are missing an id column. You cannot get your desired outcome from this data.

Based on the tables above, there is no clear way to get what you're asking for.  I understand that the second table qty of 2 and 1 added together might link to the first table.  But what is the rule or logic to allow you to total them together to know that join works?

Is it sheer luck that 4=4 and 2+1=3 or does any magic logic make it sure?

Is it guaranteed that the sum of all order quantities is equal or greater than the sum of all cust_ord quantities? Is it even guaranteed that the quantities are equal? If the order table only contains two orders for an item of a quantity of 8 each and the cust_order table contains four rows of a quantity of 4 each for that item, which custorder to link to which order? From the quantities alone we could link each two cust_orders to one order. Please describe precisely which rules shall apply.

Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using. A SQL solution will probably require a recursive query. DBMS may or may not not support recursive queries or differ in syntax.

If I understand, you need to "spread" sell orders from customers on purchase orders to supplier.
I had a similar problem time ago, my solution was to explode all quantities from both purchase and sell orders into an "priority ordered list" of qty 1 and then to join the two lists and finally to regroup them.
This output is a little different from your request, because it fulfills customer orders with mixed purchase orders, but it respects order priority.
Your question is not very clear, so I will share my experience hoping you will find it useful.
Explode purchase orders this way:
SELECT Item, Order_num, 1 Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY Item ORDER BY Order_num) n
FROM Order O
JOIN FN_NUMBERS((SELECT MAX(Qty) n from Order)) N ON O.Qty>=N.n


ItemOrder_numQtyn

A123b11
A123b12
A123b13
A123c14
A123c15
A123c16
A123c17

Explode sell order table this way:
SELECT Item, cust_ord, 1 Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY Item ORDER BY cust_ord) n
FROM Cust_order O
JOIN FN_NUMBERS((SELECT MAX(Qty) n from Cust_order)) N ON O.Qty>=N.n


itemcust_ordqtyn

A12v11
A12v12
Afrg413
Afrg414
Afrg415
Afrg416
Agtd.17

Then you can join the two tables by item and n to get:
;WITH
SO AS (
    SELECT Item, cust_ord, 1 Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY Item ORDER BY cust_ord) n
    FROM Cust_order O
    JOIN FN_NUMBERS((SELECT MAX(Qty) n from Cust_order)) N ON O.Qty>=N.n
),
PO AS (
    SELECT Item, Order_num, 1 Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY Item ORDER BY Order_num) n
    FROM Order O
    JOIN FN_NUMBERS((SELECT MAX(Qty) n from Order)) N ON O.Qty>=N.n
)
SELECT SO.Item, SO.n, SO.cust_ord, PO.Order_num, SO.Qty qty_ord, PO.Qty qty_disp
FROM SO
LEFT JOIN PO ON PO.Item = SO.Item AND PO.n = SO.n


itemncust_ordOrder_numqty_ordqty_disp

A112v 123b11
A212v 123b11
A3frg4123b11
A4frg4123c11
A5frg4123c11
A6frg4123c11
A7gtd.123c11

Group by and get output:
;WITH
SO AS (
    SELECT Item, cust_ord, 1 Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY Item ORDER BY cust_ord) n
    FROM Cust_order O
    JOIN FN_NUMBERS((SELECT MAX(Qty) n from Cust_order)) N ON O.Qty>=N.n
),
PO AS (
    SELECT Item, Order_num, 1 Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY Item ORDER BY Order_num) n
    FROM Order O
    JOIN FN_NUMBERS((SELECT MAX(Qty) n from Order)) N ON O.Qty>=N.n
)
SELECT SO.Item, SO.cust_ord, PO.Order_num, SUM(SO.Qty) qty_ord, SUM(PO.Qty) qty_disp
FROM SO
LEFT JOIN PO ON PO.Item = SO.Item AND PO.n = SO.n
GROUP BY SO.Item, SO.cust_ord, PO.Order_num


itempurchase_ordcust_ordqty_ordqty_disp

A12v 123b22
Afrg4123b41
Afrg4123c43
Agtd.123c11

Pay attention to FN_NUMBERS(n), it is a function that returns only one column with numbers from 1 to n, you need it in you database, there are many ways to do it,
just google for "tally tables" or look here.
I use the following:
CREATE FUNCTION FN_NUMBERS(
     @MAX INT
)
RETURNS @N TABLE (N INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)  
BEGIN
     WITH
       Pass0 as (select '1' as C union all select '1'),       --2 rows
       Pass1 as (select '1' as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),--4 rows
       Pass2 as (select '1' as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),--16 rows
       Pass3 as (select '1' as C from Pass2 as A, Pass2 as B),--256 rows
       Pass4 as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass3 as A, Pass3 as B)    --65536 rows
       ,Tally as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass4 as A, Pass2 as B, Pass1 as C)  --4194304 rows
       --,Tally as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass4 as A, Pass3 as B)               --16777216 rows
       --,Tally as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass4 as A, Pass4 as B)               --4294836225 rows
     INSERT INTO @N
     SELECT TOP (@MAX) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C) AS N
     FROM Tally
     RETURN
END

